# How do I read a binary file in BigEndian order to a record?

Tags: binary, ada, endianness

I have a binary file format that is written in BigEndian order. The files are of varying size so I can't use Sequential_IO for this, as I need to read different types.

The problem is, when using Stream_IO, I can't find a way to use BigEndian, and Scalar_Storage_Order also doesn't affect anything. Also, I'm a very fresh beginner at Ada and overall tips and suggestions to the code are very welcome.

```
share.adb:
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Streams.Stream_IO; use Ada.Streams.Stream_IO;
with Ada.Streams;           use Ada.Streams;

package body Share is

   procedure Read_Share (Segment_Size : Positive; Required_Shares : Positive)
   is
      --  Ceiling function
      Block_Size : constant Positive :=
        (Segment_Size + (Required_Shares - 1)) / Required_Shares;
      type Block is array (Integer range 0 .. Block_Size) of Byte;

      S               : Stream_Access;
      Share_File      : File_Type;
      My_Share_Header : Share_Header;
   begin
      Open (Share_File, In_File, "../go-tahoe/3");
      S := Stream (Share_File);
      Share_Header'Read (S, My_Share_Header);
      My_Share_Header.Block_Size := Unsigned_32 (Block_Size);
      Display_Share_Content (My_Share_Header);

      Close (Share_File);
      --  Read_Blocks (My_Share_Header, Share_File);

      --  Now My_Share contains the values read from the binary file
   end Read_Share;

   procedure Display_Share_Content (My_Share_Header : Share_Header) is
   begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line
        ("Share version: " &
         Interfaces.Unsigned_32'Image (My_Share_Header.Version));
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line
        ("Share Data Length: " &
         Interfaces.Unsigned_32'Image (My_Share_Header.Data_Length));
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line
        ("Lease Number: " &
         Interfaces.Unsigned_32'Image (My_Share_Header.Lease_number));
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line
        ("Share version: " &
         Interfaces.Unsigned_32'Image (My_Share_Header.Version));
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line
        ("Block Size: " &
         Interfaces.Unsigned_32'Image (My_Share_Header.Block_Size));
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line
        ("Data Size: " &
         Interfaces.Unsigned_32'Image (My_Share_Header.Data_Size));
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line
        ("Data offset: " &
         Interfaces.Unsigned_32'Image (My_Share_Header.Data_Offset));
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line
        ("Plaintext hash tree offset: " &
         Interfaces.Unsigned_32'Image
           (My_Share_Header.Plaintext_Hash_Tree_Offset));
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line
        ("Crypttext hash tree offset: " &
         Interfaces.Unsigned_32'Image
           (My_Share_Header.Crypttext_Hash_Tree_Offset));
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line
        ("Block hashes offset: " &
         Interfaces.Unsigned_32'Image (My_Share_Header.Block_Hashes_Offset));
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line
        ("Share hashes offset: " &
         Interfaces.Unsigned_32'Image (My_Share_Header.Share_Hashes_Offset));
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line
        ("URI Extension Length and URI Extension block offset: " &
         Interfaces.Unsigned_32'Image (My_Share_Header.URI_Extension_Offset));
   end Display_Share_Content;

   procedure Read_Blocks
     (My_Share_Header : Share_Header; Share_File : File_Type)
   is
      Total_Blocks : Interfaces.Unsigned_32 := My_Share_Header.Data_Size;
   begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put ("");

   end Read_Blocks;
end Share;

share.ads:
with Interfaces; use Interfaces;
with System;     use System;
with Ada.Streams.Stream_IO;

package Share is

   type Byte is new Interfaces.Unsigned_8;
   type Kilobyte is array (Integer range 0 .. 1_023) of Byte;
   type Kilobyte_array is array (Integer range <>) of Kilobyte;

   type Share_Header is record
      Version                    : Unsigned_32;
      Data_Length                : Unsigned_32;
      Lease_number               : Unsigned_32;
      Version_Junk               : Unsigned_32;
      --  unused as it can be calculated from the URI
      Block_Size                 : Unsigned_32;
      Data_Size                  : Unsigned_32;
      Data_Offset                : Unsigned_32;
      Plaintext_Hash_Tree_Offset : Unsigned_32;
      Crypttext_Hash_Tree_Offset : Unsigned_32;
      Block_Hashes_Offset        : Unsigned_32;
      Share_Hashes_Offset        : Unsigned_32;
      URI_Extension_Offset       : Unsigned_32;
   end record;

   for Share_Header use record
      Version at 0 range 0 .. 32;
      --  Data_Length                : Unsigned_32;
      --  Lease_number               : Unsigned_32;
      --  Version_Junk               : Unsigned_32;
      --  --  unused as it can be calculated from the URI
      --  Block_Size                 : Unsigned_32;
      --  Data_Size                  : Unsigned_32;
      --  Data_Offset                : Unsigned_32;
      --  Plaintext_Hash_Tree_Offset : Unsigned_32;
      --  Crypttext_Hash_Tree_Offset : Unsigned_32;
      --  Block_Hashes_Offset        : Unsigned_32;
      --  Share_Hashes_Offset        : Unsigned_32;
      --  URI_Extension_Offset       : Unsigned_32;
   end record;

   for Share_Header'Bit_Order use High_Order_First;
   for Share_Header'Scalar_Storage_Order use High_Order_First;

   procedure Read_Share (Segment_Size : Positive; Required_Shares : Positive);
   procedure Display_Share_Content (My_Share_Header : Share_Header);
   procedure Read_Blocks
     (My_Share_Header : Share_Header;
      Share_File      : Ada.Streams.Stream_IO.File_Type);
end Share;
```

Tried defining the component clauses to not much success, different bit orders, modifying the Stream_IO storage arrays.

Comment: I don't use Ada, but in C-like languages it's common to reacd byte by byte and then fix up the ordering.  So for an int32 you'd read 4 bytes then stuff them into the int in the reverse order, with something like a `ReadInt32BE(int32& i, stream& s)` helper function that you've written or gotten from a library.  Hopefully someone else can chime in with a better answer.

Comment: I do it byte-wise, with a swap if the endianness of the computer (this can be detected) is different than the endianness of the stream.

Comment: Could you add a snippet of example code for that? The whole idea behind Ada programming is still very confusing for me, so I'm not sure how to do it properly

Comment: In C++ it might be (read b1, b2, b3, b4) then int32 = (b1 << 24) + (b2 << 16) + (b3 << 8) + b4 , where << is a bit shift.  I don't know the Ada for this, and you do need to copy the bytes into ints.  You could use multiplication instead of bit shifts.

Comment: @DaveS int32 = (b1 * 2 ** 24) + (b2 * 2 ** 16) + (b3 * 2 ** 8) + b4; would be how we do it in Ada (though this won't work without type conversions on b1, b2, b3, b4 because b1, b2, b3, b4 will be of int8_t (Byte in this case) which is different from int32_t). There is likely much more elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for a very late answer, but to complete the answer set: IMO the default method here is to derive a new type from Unsigned_32 and write your own stream 'Read attribute for this type, to use whatever encoding you need, in this case a big-endian encoding.

So, in share.ads, I would add:

```
type Word is new Interfaces.Unsigned_32;
-- An Unsigned_32 with big-endian encoding in input streams.

procedure Read_Word (
   Stream : access Ada.Streams.Root_Stream_Type'Class;
   Item   : out Word'Base);

for Word'Read use Read_Word;
```

I would then change the type of all relevant Share_Header components from Unsigned_32 to Word, and in share.adb add:

```
procedure Read_Word (
  Stream : access Ada.Streams.Root_Stream_Type'Class;
  Item   : out Word'Base)
is
   B1, B2, B3, B4 : Byte;
begin
   Byte'Read (Stream, B1);
   Byte'Read (Stream, B2);
   Byte'Read (Stream, B3);
   Byte'Read (Stream, B4);
   
   Item :=
         Shift_Left (Word (B1), 24)
      or Shift_Left (Word (B2), 16)
      or Shift_Left (Word (B3),  8)
      or             Word (B4);
   
end Read_Word;
```

As you see, the Read_Word procedure says exactly in which order the bytes are read and how they are composed into a Word -- you have full control.

The compiler will now automatically use Read_Byte in Share_Header'Read.

I use this method extensively to read various kinds of binary files such as ELF and other executable program formats. This solution is entirely standard Ada and does not rely on any GNAT-specific stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested solution! It's simple enough to wrap my head around and just works.

Answer (score 2):

Most of your replies have been GNAT-specific, but of course it is possible to convert input bytes into an internal integer value portably.

```
generic -- Endian_Conversions
   type Unsigned is mod <>;
package Endian_Conversions is
   pragma Assert (Unsigned'Size in 16 | 32 | 64 | 128);

   Byte_Size : constant := 8;

   type Byte is mod 2 ** Byte_Size with Size => Byte_Size;

   Bytes_Per_Value : constant Positive := Unsigned'Size / Byte_Size;

   type Byte_List is array (1 .. Bytes_Per_Value) of Byte;
   pragma Assert (Byte_List'Size = Bytes_Per_Value * Byte_Size);

   function Value (List : in Byte_List; Big_Endian : in Boolean := False) return Unsigned;
   -- Converts the Bytes in List to an Unsigned
   -- If Big_Endian, the Bytes in List are in big-endian order [List (1) is the MSB]
   -- Otherwise the Bytes in List are in little-endian order [List (1) is the LSB]
end Endian_Conversions;

with Ada.Unchecked_Conversion;
with System;

package body Endian_Conversions is
   function Value (List : in Byte_List; Big_Endian : in Boolean := False) return Unsigned is
      procedure Reverse_Bytes (List : in out Byte_List) with
         Post => (for all I in 1 .. List'Last / 2 => List (I) = List'Old (List'Last - I + 1) );
  
      function To_Unsigned is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (Source => Byte_List, Target => Unsigned);
  
      procedure Reverse_Bytes (List : in out Byte_List) is
         procedure Swap (Left : in out Byte; Right : in out Byte) with
            Post => Left = Right'Old and Right = Left'Old;
        
         procedure Swap (Left : in out Byte; Right : in out Byte) is
            Temp : constant Byte := Left;
         begin -- Swap
            Left := Right;
            Right := Temp;
         end Swap;
        
         Last : Positive := List'Last;
      begin -- Reverse_Bytes
         Flip : for I in 1 .. Last / 2 loop
            Swap (Left => List (I), Right => List (Last) );
            Last := Last - 1;
         end loop Flip;
      end Reverse_Bytes;
  
      Local : Byte_List := List;
  
      use type System.Bit_Order;
   begin -- Value
      if (not Big_Endian and System.Default_Bit_Order = System.High_Order_First) or
         (Big_Endian and System.Default_Bit_Order = System.Low_Order_First)
      then
         Reverse_Bytes (List => Local);
      end if;
  
      return To_Unsigned (Local);
   end Value;
end Endian_Conversions;

with Ada.Text_IO;
with Endian_Conversions;
with Interfaces;

procedure Endian_Test is
   subtype U32 is Interfaces.Unsigned_32;
   use type U32;

   package U32_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Modular_IO (Num => U32);

   package Conversions is new Endian_Conversions (Unsigned => U32);

   List : constant Conversions.Byte_List := (16, 17, 18, 19);
begin -- Endian_Test
   U32_IO.Put (Item => Conversions.Value (List), Base => 16);
   Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
   U32_IO.Put (Item => Conversions.Value (List, Big_Endian => True), Base => 16);
   Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
end Endian_Test;
```

This compiles and gives identical results with GNAT/Linux and ObjectAda/Windows, both x86 (little-endian).

```
$ ./endian_test 
16#13121110#
16#10111213#
```

Comment: Thank you. I am bookmarking this answer as a thing I will probably need in the future. For now I'll stick to the `-xdr` switch mentioned below, but will have to try to make this not exclusive to GNAT.

Comment: Why shouldn’t `Unsigned’Size` be 8?

Comment: There is no endian issue with 1-byte modular type. The algorithm will do nothing correctly for that case, but it seems clearer for the pkg to be for the cases where a conversion may actually be needed.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way to convert individual unsigned integers is by shift's & add's. An advantage is that you don't need to figure out, or force, the endianness of the internal representation. This solution is portable.

```
with Interfaces;
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Conversions is

  subtype U8  is Interfaces.Unsigned_8;
  subtype U32 is Interfaces.Unsigned_32;

  type Buffer is array (Natural range <>) of U8;

  type Endianness is (big, little);

  generic
    type Number is mod <>;
    bytes : Positive;
    stream_endianness : Endianness;
  function Gen_Convert (from : Buffer) return Number;

  function Gen_Convert (from : Buffer) return Number is
    result : Number := 0;
    pos : Integer;
  begin
    pragma Assert (from'Length = bytes);
    case stream_endianness is
      when big    => pos := from'First;
      when little => pos := from'Last;
    end case;
    for count in 1 .. bytes loop
      result := result * 256 + Number (from (pos));
      case stream_endianness is
        when big    => pos := pos + 1;
        when little => pos := pos - 1;
      end case;
    end loop;
    return result;
  end;

  function Convert_From_Big    is new Gen_Convert (U32, 4, big);
  function Convert_From_Little is new Gen_Convert (U32, 4, little);

  use Ada.Text_IO;

begin
  --  16#01020304# = 16909060
  --  NB: from -O1 level, GNAT optimizes the following
  --      as: "Put_Line (16909060'Image)" !
  Put_Line (Convert_From_Big    ((1,2,3,4))'Image);
  Put_Line (Convert_From_Little ((4,3,2,1))'Image);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use the `gnatbind` switch `-xdr`. See the [GNAT RM 6.32](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gnat_rm/html/gnat_rm/gnat_rm/implementation_advice.html#rm-13-13-2-1-6-stream-oriented-attributes):

> The default implementation [of stream-oriented attrbutes] is based on direct binary representations and is therefore target- and endianness-dependent. To address this issue, GNAT also supplies an alternate implementation of the stream attributes Read and Write, which uses the target-independent XDR standard representation for scalar types. This XDR alternative can be enabled via the binder switch -xdr.

(XDR is fundamentally big-endian)

---

Here’s a worked example: it reads the first 8 bytes of its own source file as two `Unsigned_32` record components.

```ada
--  abcd  << those are the 8 bytes we're going to read.

with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Streams.Stream_IO;
with Interfaces;

procedure Adam is
   type Rec is record
      U1 : Interfaces.Unsigned_32;
      U2 : Interfaces.Unsigned_32;
   end record;
   package U32_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Modular_IO (Interfaces.Unsigned_32);

   Data_File : Ada.Streams.Stream_IO.File_Type;
   Str : Ada.Streams.Stream_IO.Stream_Access;

   Read_Value : Rec;
begin
   --  I'm just going to use the Ada source file, since we know it'll
   --  be there!
   Ada.Streams.Stream_IO.Open
     (Data_File, Ada.Streams.Stream_IO.In_File, "adam.adb");
   Str := Ada.Streams.Stream_IO.Stream (Data_File);

   --  Read the first 8 bytes of adam.adb, as big-endian if the binder
   --  argument -xdr is given, as native (most likely little-endian)
   --  otherwise.
   Rec'Read (Str, Read_Value);
   Ada.Streams.Stream_IO.Close (Data_File);

   U32_IO.Put (Read_Value.U1, Base => 16);
   Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
   U32_IO.Put (Read_Value.U2, Base => 16);
   Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
end Adam;
```

Without XDR:

```
$ gnatmake adam.adb -f
gcc -c adam.adb
gnatbind -x adam.ali
gnatlink adam.ali
$ ./adam
16#20202D2D#
16#64636261#
```

With XDR:

```
$ gnatmake adam.adb -f -bargs -xdr
gcc -c adam.adb
gnatbind -xdr -x adam.ali
gnatlink adam.ali
$ ./adam
16#2D2D2020#
16#61626364#
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to get your data as a bunch of bytes, then to convert them to your record using Ada.Unchecked_Conversion, provided you use the Scalar_Storage_Order clause.

```
with Ada.Unchecked_Conversion;
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Interfaces;
with System;

procedure BE_Test is

  subtype U8  is Interfaces.Unsigned_8;
  subtype U32 is Interfaces.Unsigned_32;

  type Buffer is array (Natural range <>) of U8;

  type Header is record
    Version    : U32;
    Signature  : String (1 .. 4);
    Code       : Buffer (1 .. 4);
  end record;

  for Header use record
    Version    at 0 range 0 .. 31;
    Signature  at 4 range 0 .. 31;
    Code       at 8 range 0 .. 31;
  end record;

  for Header'Bit_Order use System.High_Order_First;
  for Header'Scalar_Storage_Order use System.High_Order_First;

  function Convert is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (Buffer, Header);

  h : Header;
  
  use Ada.Text_IO;
  
begin
  --  16#01020304# = 16909060
  --  16909060 (as big endian), then "ABCD", then 11 12 13 14
  h := Convert ((1, 2, 3, 4, 65, 66, 67, 68, 11, 12, 13, 14));
  Put_Line (h.Version'Image);
  Put_Line (h.Signature);
  for i in h.Code'Range loop
    Put_Line (h.Code (i)'Image);
  end loop;
end;
```

Two remarks there:

- Scalar_Storage_Order is GNAT-only
- GNAT issues warnings for arrays within the record (Signature, Code in the above example): `warning: scalar storage order specified for "Header" does not apply to component`. The warnings are harmless (the behaviour is what we expect), but a bit nasty. Not sure how to remove them in a proper way.